# Can I use content affiliation without using a real subdomain with Domain Access?

Tags: 7, multi-sites, domain-access, subsites

The Affiliated Content system invoked by Domain Access is perfect for my need to allow multiple "sub-sites" to run from one Drupal installation (i.e a multi-site approach to each part of a larger organization).

However, I can't use subdomains. Is it still possible to Domain Access to partition my D7 site into "domains" of ACLs, users, content, etc. if I'm only allowed to edit the path after "hostname/"?